# Python process multiple files iteratively, without an explicit for loop

Tags: python, unix, command-line, io

I have a script that uses a large chunk of text to train a model. The way it's written now I can either read from a file or stdin

```
parser.add_argument('-i', help='input_file', default=sys.stdin)
... # do a bunch of other stuff
if args.i is sys.stdin:
    m.train(args.i)
else:
    m.train(open(args.i, 'r'))
```

then I can call my script as:

```
python myscript.py -i trainingdata.txt
```

or

```
cat trainingdata.txt | python myscript.py
```

The second version is especially useful if I want to search the filesystem, and use multiple files to train the model. However this becomes tricky, due to the pipe, if I simultaneously try to profile using `cProfiler` i.e.

```
python -m cProfile myscript.py ...
```

I know that I can send it multiple files using the `-i` option, and iterate over the files, but then I will have to change the behaviour of the `train()` method to avoid overwriting data.

Is there a good way to open an IO channel, for the lack of a better expression, that concatenates the input without explicitly reading and writing line by line?

Comment: I feel like you might want to look into Pandas.

Comment: @mauve i am already working with pandas in this project, what specifically are you referring to?

Comment: I thought it would help with the "not reading in line by line" part. I have some code where I open each file in a directory, read it into DataFrames, concatenate the DataFrames, sort it by time, and output as 10-hour chunks in csv form.

Comment: The `fileinput` module does a great job at concatenating files given as parameters and optionaly the standard input. Maybe you should look at it...

Comment: @SergeBallesta If I understand it right, it's not compatible with argparse which is necessary in my case. I have multiple different CL arguments that need handling. But nevertheless it's a good tip, I'll try to keep it in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) open files and use a generator to `yield` open files from the filenames:

```
from itertools import chain

def yield_open(filenames):
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            yield file

def train(file):
    for line in file:
        print(line, end='')
    print()

files = chain.from_iterable(yield_open(filenames=['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']))
train(files)
```

this has the added benefit that only one of your files is open at the time.

you could also use that as a 'data pipeline' (may be more readable):

```
file_gen = yield_open(filenames=['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'])
files = chain.from_iterable(file_gen)
train(files)
```

Comment: Interesting.. that should imitate the behaviour of the piped `cat` command.. Is there a more generic way to write the `with` statement for an arbitrary (potentially large) number of files?

Comment: @posdef tried to do that. is this more or less what you mean?